Will This Async Method Return True or False?
I am trying to check if the _isLoggedIn variable has been set to True or False or Empty. The Boolean variable will be set after the user is logged in. Assuming the user is YET to login and not records of isLoggedIn has been set or stored. What will be the return value of this method below?
  Future<bool> userIsLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') as bool;
    return _isLoggedIn;
  }


Type casting will not change the actual value type, so if for example you say "string" as boolean, the "string" will always stay a string and it will not be converted to a boolean. Type casting with as keyword only tricks the typechecker. and it's only useful within the code editor. I'm just guessing as a typescript developer, I am not a dart developer - I just wanted to know if my answer was correct. so please let me know if my answer as correct or not.

The return value of the function is a Future<bool>.  The returned Future eventually will complete with a value of either true or false (or the Future might fail with an exception, such as if the as bool cast fails).  That's it.

@jamesdlin I took a look at the return function, and it's of type bool? - not Future (I thought it was like that myself).
see below answer.
(Or am I mistaken?)

@MendelG Depends on which function the OP is asking about.  I was presuming the question is about the userIsLoggedIn function.

@jamesdlin Right, I just realized :)

If you take a look at the implmenetion of getBool. You'll see:
bool? getBool(String key) => _preferenceCache[key] as bool?;

which means,that if the isLoggedIn key is not set in SharedPreferences, then prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') will return null.
Now, since _isLoggedIn is declared as a bool, casting null (when the value doesn't exist) to bool with
as bool will cause an error.
Instead, I'd go with:
Future<bool> userIsLoggedIn() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool? _isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
  return _isLoggedIn ?? false;
}

The null-aware operator (??) is used to provide a default value (false) if _isLoggedIn is null.
now , the return value of the function is a Future<bool>. The returned Future will eventually complete with a value of either true or false (or the Future might fail with an exception, such as in this case, if the as bool cast fails, e.g. the the value isn't found in SharedPrefs).
